# How to retrieve the current script's path in Fish shell

Tags: fish

In bash, we can retrieve the current script's path by `$0` variable, so if any script has a dependency resource which is under the same directory as the script directory, we can use it even when we're not executing the script in the script's directory.

How can I retrieve the current script's path in fish shell?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`status --current-filename` is what you're looking for.

Note that this handles both sourced and executed files, while $0 in bash is only for executed files.

Comment: How do you get the absolute path?

Comment: Use this command to get the current script's absolute path: `set SCRIPT_DIR (cd (dirname (status --current-filename)); and pwd)`.

Comment: Another workaround to get the current script's absolute path: `set -l script_dir (realpath (dirname (status -f)))`

Comment: note that fish doesn't have subshells so the `cd` above will actually change the directory